# Azure Devops remove specific user from specific organization using Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

Example, I want to Offboard Tiger from Azure Develops Organization BigZoo (Tiger has 3 Azure organization, BigZoo, SmallZoo, middleZoo--I only want to remove tiger from BigZoo)

Use this Azure CLI in the Azure Cloudshell Powershell will be working

```
az devops user remove --user tiger
                      [--org BigZoo]
                      [--yes]
```

But it does not work in Azure function-->Azure function use PowerShell environment--> CloudPowerShell can read AzureCLi but Powershell In AzureFunction cannot read anything related with Az

So, if I only want use powershell without any help from Azure CLI, there are some module but all imported module is remove user from all Organizations--> Not remove user from specific organization

Any suggestion? Remove user from specific AzureDevops Organization. Using API seems too complex . Any good idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this but there is the VSTeam powershell module in the PowerShell gallery which wraps the Azure Devops API.

This has a function called: Remove-VSTeamUserEntitlement

Docs here:
https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Remove-VSTeamUserEntitlement

Module here:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTeam/

Add the module to the `Requirements.psd1` file of your azure functions project and you should be able to utilise it.

Comment: I put a upvote on your answer because it helps but actually it is not the real answer. This one I know long time ago, but the weakness of this Remove-VsTeamUserEntitlement is that we don't have the organization paramenter.....Like Cat has 3 organization..if i use this one, how does this one know which organziation to be removed it may remove all organizations Thanks

Comment: You can set the context of the account being used using: https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Set-VSTeamAccount and either have a different endpoint for each org which accepts a POST request and loads different identities so as not to mix the Azure DevOps organisation up.